# What is the optimal way of writing large data objects to AerospikeDB?

Tags: aerospike

My application makes a call to third party API for search results depending on the users request. We would like to store these results in a cache for easy retrieval. The problem is these search results are large in size, approx. around 11MB. Since the size of the object is large and the application is multi threaded, multiple calls are being made to aerospike simultaneously and aerospike is constantly throwing the InvalidNode exception. Is there a way I can store the object and see low latency results?

Comment: The InvalidNode exception shouldn't be related to the fact that you are making multiple calls to Aerospike simultaneously. Something is not right in the setup, and maybe the client is not able to see all nodes in the cluster. Sharing the exact exception received from the client may help. (It also seems like the client is not a recent one). Which client is it by the way?

Comment: I am using the latest one from the AWS market place. 4.2.0. The install was a simple and straight forward step by step on an r4.xlarge ec2 instance. There is only 1 node in cluster.

Answer (score 3):

To store large objects and use the database as a cache, you can use storage-engine memory that can store much larger objects than the persistent storage option (SSDs:configurable - 8MB max, 1MB default, 128KB for best SSD performance). Latency will more be a function of the size of the objects and the network data transfer rate in your case. For example, an 11 MB object (=88 Mbits) at 10 G-bits-per-second total node network interface (AWS r5 instance example) and with replication from and incoming to a node, taking additional bandwidth, you can write at 10*1024/88 = 116, then 116/3 = ~ 38 writes per second per node. (3: client write, out replica write, incoming replica write).  So to achieve better latency, either you need more network bandwidth per node or horizontally scale your cluster so more nodes are handling incoming writes.

The invalid node issue as discussed in the comment is more a configuration / clustering / connectivity issue - not related to latency.

Comment: incoming writes seem to be going along smoothly, however, its on read that it throws the invalid node exception. I tried reducing the size of the objects we are storing and the cache seems to be working fine.

Comment: Since Aerospike is designed to switch from storage engine memory to disk and vice versa through a rolling upgrade, without having to shut down the cluster, the recommendation is not not exceed 8MB object limit even in memory.  I am not sure, but there may be internal limit when reading back of max 10MB on network socket buffers.  So, I would recommend, in a single record, don't exceed 8MB and even at that size, due network bandwidth limits, you may see high read/write latency.